# PDO create collation for mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, collation

With the sqlite driver I can use this undocumented function:

```
$pdo->sqliteCreateCollation('NATSORT', 'strnatcasecmp');
```

Is there any way to do it with mysql too? I tried `mysqlCreateCollation()` but it gives undefined error.